# Spring MVC 4 Handle and Display message on session timeout for selected pages in application

Tags: jquery, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Application is used for remote monitoring where user analyze data. It has several dashboards, setting pages, historical report pages, etc.

My requirement is, for some pages (Example: **settings page, user profile page**) **session timeout should be applied** and for some pages (Example: **dashboard page, report page**, etc) **should be accessible to the user without login** (*no user login/session is required*).

Till now I have tried few things:

1. Using filter and the FilterChain to redirect the response.
2. In JSP, based on the `setMaxInactiveInterval()` show a popup message on session expiry and redirect to some page.

Nothing worked till now.

I am using *Spring MVC 4.0.0, JSP, HTML, jQuery*

My question is:

1. How do I handle session and session timeout for some pages with a session timed out message?
2. How do I allow user to view without a session/user login for some pages? (No login is required)

Comment: Downvoted, since it is unclear what you are asking. What have you tried so far, and what is not working`?

Comment: imho you are mixing 2 things, session timeout and security. For security use Spring Security which is basically a matter of configuring which URLs to protect and which not. For the session timeout, Spring Security could help but that is an all or nothing approach (unless you plugin your own implementation).